# PhantomJs click a flash button

Tags: javascript, flash, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to click at [flash](/questions/tagged/flash) elements using a forked [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) `1.10.0` version and [casperjs](/questions/tagged/casperjs) `1.0.2`.
My environment is this <kbd>[Vagrant image](http://github.com/jantimon/phantom-flash-vagrant)</kbd> which ships with a [forked phantomJS version](https://github.com/r3b/phantomjs).

The flash support works quite well however simulating clicks doesn't.
For the following showcase I took a flash button from the [adobe sample page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/button_component_as3.edu.html) and put it into a <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Da3q7/show/light/)</kbd>.

After receiving a click event the button label changes from "Click me" to "Ouch".

So the **expected result** of the following code would be:

[image: Expected result]

However the **result** is

[image: Real result]

CasperJS code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    loadPlugins: true
  }
});

casper.start("http://fiddle.jshell.net/Da3q7/show/light/");

casper.wait(1000);

// CasperJS click
casper.then(function () {
  this.echo("Click", "INFO");
  this.click('#section04example1');
});

casper.wait(1000);

casper.then(function () {
  this.echo("Screenshot", "INFO");
  this.captureSelector('button-demo.png', '#section04example1');
  this.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CasperJS invokes only javascript events which won't trigger Flash mouse events for security reasons.
However the PhantomJS `sendEvent` method invokes real browser events.

The next problem was that the element has to be visible in the current viewport which requires scolling in most cases.

In the end I wrote a small CasperJS `clickRelative`extension:

```
casper.clickRelative = function (selector, offset) {
  "use strict";

  var docSize = casper.evaluate(function () {
    return {width: document.width, height: document.height};
  });
  var position = this.getElementBounds(selector);
  if (position !== null) {

    var left = position.left + (offset.left || 0);
    var scrollX = this.page.viewportSize.width > docSize.width ? 0 :
      Math.min(left, docSize.width - this.page.viewportSize.width);

    var top = position.top + (offset.top || 0);
    var scrollY = this.page.viewportSize.height > docSize.height ? 0 :
      Math.min(top, docSize.height - this.page.viewportSize.height);

    var scrollOrig = {left: this.page.scrollPosition.left, top: this.page.scrollPosition.top};

    this.page.scrollPosition = {left: scrollX, top: scrollY};

    this.wait(10);
    this.then(function () {
      this.page.sendEvent("click", left - scrollX, top - scrollY, 'left');
    });
    this.wait(10);
    this.then(function () {
      this.page.scrollPosition = scrollOrig;
    });
  }
};
```

So now my script is able to click the button and generates the following screenshot of the flash button:

[image: Flash Button Clicked]

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    loadPlugins: true
  }
});

casper.start("http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/button_component_as3.edu.html");

casper.wait(1000);

casper.then(function () {
  this.echo("Click", "INFO");
  // The button has a margin so we have to add a little offset to the
  // click position:
  this.clickRelative('#section04example1', {left: 30, top: 15});
});

casper.wait(1000);

casper.then(function () {
  this.echo("Screenshot", "INFO");
  this.captureSelector('button-demo.png', '#section04example1');
  this.exit();
});

casper.run();
```